# IronTesseract input.AddPdf(FileName.FullName)

Tags: tesseract

how I can read just the 1st page from my pdf file??
whit my code the ocr.Read read the barcode into each pages of my file, but I nedd to read only the barcode on the right top of my 1st page, so goto to next file.

thank
fabrizio

```
IronTesseract ocr = new IronTesseract();
ocr.Configuration.ReadBarCodes = true;

string filepath =  @"\\scanner$\MIL_AE\";
string FileOutput = @"\\scanner$\MIL_AE\done\";
int nr = 0;
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
string txt = "";
string br = "";
foreach (var FileName in d.GetFiles("*.pdf"))
{
    string scan = FileName.Name;
    scan = scan.Substring(0, 8);
    if (scan == "SKM_368e")
        {
            int code = 0;
            using (OcrInput input = new OcrInput())
            {
                input.AddPdf(FileName.FullName);
                OcrResult result = ocr.Read(input);
                foreach (var barcode in result.Barcodes)
                    {
                        br = barcode.Value.Substring(0, 1);
                        if (br != "W" && barcode.Value.Length == 10)
                        {
                            string res = nr.ToString() + " - " + FileName.Name + " - " + barcode.Value ;
                            Console.WriteLine(res);
                        }
                    }

            }
        }          
}
```